# conditionally set marker in angular-google map use on angular 4

Tags: angular, google-maps, angular-google-maps

how to the possible way to set google marker in angular conditionally example my data is

```
{
    "lat":23.830625,
    "lng":90.417662,
    "zipcode":31208,
    "city":"Macon",
    "drivetime":33,
    "distance":7,
    "dms":33,
    "market":32,
    "market-share":"00"
},
{   
    "lat":23.831095,
    "lng": 90.417080,
    "zipcode":31206,
    "city":"Macon",
    "drivetime":45,
    "distance":10,
    "dms":45,
    "market":580,
    "market-share":"00"
}
```

**When dms is less then dms>40 then add yellow marker dms>20 then add red otherwise default**

```
<sebm-google-map 
  [latitude]="lat"
  [longitude]="lng"
  [zoom]="zoom"
  [disableDefaultUI]="false"
  [zoomControl]="false"
  >
  <sebm-google-map-marker 
      *ngFor="let m of markers; let i = index"
      [latitude]="m.lat"
      [longitude]="m.lng"
       [iconUrl]="if(m.dms>40){default}else if(m.dms>50){green} else {red}"
      >
  </sebm-google-map-marker>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the Angular / Typescript conditionnal operator

```
[input]="m.dms>30 ? ifTrueValue : elseValue"
```

In your ts or in the html, add your boolean condition like above, and two options :

```
ifTrueValue = "YelowIcon.png"; and elseValue="RedIcon.png";
```

Best ;)

Answer (score 0):

**I hope, this is the best for template nexted conditions**

```
[iconUrl]="(data.dms>50)? markericon1: (data.dms>35)? markericon2 : markericon3"
```